# What is the exact use of single quote in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I am running a Hive query in a particulat table which has columns named "CNTY" and "BNTY".I can see if i run a query with "LIKE" in CNTY it was working fine.

```
select CNTY from <table_name> where CNTY like ('As%')
```

result :

```
Aspire
Asthene
Ashara
```

When i try to pull BNTY

select BNTY from table where BNTY like ('S%')

Above code doesn't work.

But if run without single quotes its working fine.

select BNTY from <table_name> where BNTY like (S%)

Result :

```
ST
SP
SM
```

Both were same data type[string]

Comment: Can you share what you mean by not working? Do you get error or empty result?

Comment: `select BNTY from <table_name> where BNTY like (S%)` should not work, what version of hive you are using?